# Ssh not working when host is taken using grep

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, grep

When I'm hardcoding i. e.

```
server1=ip-10.237.40.10-aws-n-myhost
ssh - i /home/<passwordfile>  akhil@$server1
```

It is working,but when I'm greping the host from other file its not working 
Eg:

```
server2=$(grep - e host /home/akhil/configuration. File | awk FS, '{print $2} ' )
echo $server2
ssh - i /home/<passwordfile>  akhil@$server2
```

While printing server 2 is fine, but when it is used in ssh I'm getting a error saying : `not known host name.`
I want to automate the script with a configuration file so that when ever the cluster changes I could simply change the ip address in configfile instead of changing in all my scripts.

I need help in this. 
Thanks

Comment: (1) `awk FS,` is an error and should fail utterly -- did you mean `awk -F,` ? (2) did your file come from or via a Windows (or MSDOS+) system? If so it probably has CRLF line endings, so if field 2 was the last field your servername actually contains a CR which looks visually the same but is wrong

Comment: Also in `- i`, `- e`, and `.../configuration. File` there probably shouldn't be a space. Please paste your commands exaclty as you use them.